# Naive Bayesian Classifier for Workload Prediction

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I want to use *Naive Bayesian Classifier* for predicting the workload of a device (e.g., network card). I have a series of observations that represent the inter-arrival times of the requests. The series of the data is represented as 0,1,1,1,0,0,1, ... where 1 represent an inter-arrival time which is longer than a *Break Even Time* and 0 represent an inter-arrival time that is shorter than the *Break Even Time*. I want to predict the next inter-arrival time to be **short** or **long** *(shorter than break even time, or longer)*. Therefore, I have two classes, i.e., short and long.  I have gone through the theory of Naive Bayesian Classifier, but I have confusion about implementing it in MATLAB or C++. I don't know with how many features/data should I start the learning process and how do I calculate the maximum likelihood for a predicted class. Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How much data do you have? Why don't you try [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) first (no programming needed, you can just try different algorithms by simply supplying a data file)?

Comment: Let's say I have a thousand inter-arrival times (as mentioned above). Since I have only a single feature (inter-arrival times) and two classes, i.e., short and long, I do this as follows: first I find the prior probabilities of the two classes from the training sample. Then I find the conditional probabilities of the input features for each class assignment. Now, if I apply Bayesian rule to calculate the _maximum a posteriori_ for the two classes, does it give me the probabilities of the two classes (short and long) for the next inter-arrival period?

Answer (score 2):

You can begin with [Markov Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_model). In Markov Model you assume that probability of each state is given only by the previous state. For example in a series like 000111100111 you get following transition occurrences:

```
           Xn=0   Xn=1
X(n-1)=0     3     2
X(n-1)=1     1     5
```

Written in probability:

```
           Xn=0   Xn=1
X(n-1)=0    0.6    0.4
X(n-1)=1    0.17   0.83
```

And you can use it as a feature: you scan all the training series and note frequency of transitions from 0->0, 0->1, 1->0 and 1->1. For classification you look at the last state of your query string and look up the probability that the next state will be 0, or respectively 1, in the transition matrix. And based on that you choose the more likely state.

Even thought this approach is simple, it commonly works very well.

Once you make it work with the one previous digit you can begin to look at the two previous digits and use them as another feature. Hence the transition matrix for the example can look like:

```
                     Xn=0   Xn=1
X(n-2)=0, X(n-1)=0     1     2
X(n-2)=0, X(n-1)=1     0     2
X(n-2)=1, X(n-1)=0     1     0
X(n-2)=1, X(n-1)=1     1     3
```

And you can even expand it to the last three digits and so on.

To combine the features together you just multiply all the probabilities that the next state is 0 from all the features together:

```
p(next is 0)=p1(next is 0)*p2(next is 0)*p3(next is 0)*...*pn(next is 0)
```

and you can similarly calculate the probability that the next state will be 1:

```
p(next is 1)=p1(next is 1)*p2(next is 1)*p3(next is 1)*...*pn(next is 1)
```

and choose the more likely state. Of course you don't have to calculate p(next is 1) as

```
p(next is 0)+p(next is 1)=1
```

Just for illustration how this approach is effective play Rock-Paper-Scissors against the computer at [The New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/science/rock-paper-scissors.html) and click on "See What the Computer is Thinking" to see the Markov Model in action.